# Unknow column in ON clause

Tags: sql

I have the following query:

```
select p.idPerson from person p "
        + " join dog g on g.idDog = p.idDog, "
        + " tree t "
        + " join parents p1 on p1.idParents = t.idParents "
        + " join parents p2 on p2.idParents = p.idParents "
```

I've changed parameters, i know these query doesn't make sense, i'ts just to show you the structure, so my error is:

```
Unknown column 'p.idParents' in 'on clause'
```

This does even less sense, i think the error is on the "tree t", the only one which is not join, but i don't know how to solve it becuase it hasn't got any relation with the other tables to do a join.

Thanks!

Comment: don't mix explicit joins and comma delimited syntax. Use `cross join` if that's what you need

Comment: Why are you including the `tree` table if it doesn't have any connection to the others. Do you want a cross join with that?

Comment: So to solve i just have to move that "tree t" below the other ones?

Comment: If it has no relation, why is it there? Do you want a `cross join` then, instead of a multi-table select? Anyway, please tag which RDBMS this is. Also, if your book/guide doesn't say clearly that that syntax is invalid and how you would rewrite it (although you shouldn't), I suggest finding a better one.

Comment: Yes i need to have this `tree` because when i do my where clause i compare `parents p1` and `parents p2`

Comment: explicit joins are evaluated before comma separated ones. I.e. the final `on p2.idParents = p.idParents` does not know about the `p` table.

Comment: So i should move the `tree t` below all the others? But then how can i do ` join parents p1 on p1.idParents = t.idParents `

Comment: Replace the `,` with either `cross join` or `join` with an appropriate `on` clause.  I suspect you are missing a condition.